# VBA - Loading values from sheet to a multicolumn listbox

Tags: excel

I have a sheet called SAVED where from A1 to D1 are the column names and everything below are my values.

I'm automatically adding those values to a multicolumn Listbox when I click on a button. Please see below the code I'm using:

```
'Load sheet values into a into lisbox

Dim aSheet As Worksheet
Dim aRng As Range
Dim aArr

Set aSheet = Sheets("SAVED")
Set aRng = aSheet.Range("A2:D" & aSheet.Range("A" & aSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

With frmSavedValues.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = aRng.Columns.Count
    
' Working with Arrays is always faster than working with ranges

     aArr = aRng
    .List = aArr
    .TopIndex = 0
End With

If frmSavedValues.ListBox1.ListIndex <> "" Then
    frmSavedValues.Show
End If
```

As you can see, I specify that my range is from A2:D and down. This works pretty well when I have values in my sheet, but when I delete the values (leaving the column names only) it loads the column names which is not correct.

I don't understand why it's loading the column names (A1:D1).

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
Range("A" & aSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

will not stop at Row 2.

So, with A2 empty, `aRng` will reduce to `A2:A1`

You'll need to specifically check that there is data in row 2 to avoid your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, makes sense!